# How can I get title attribute of clicked button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, dom-events

I'm working on small angular project, and there are 3 buttons on my form, I would like to receive their title when they are clicked. They are clicked normally one by one, what I've tried so far:

Here is my html:

```
<div class="extra-btns">
  <button type="button" title="Title 1"  (click)="getMyTitleOne($event)" class="btn xbutton-square" style="font-size: 16px;"><i class="fas fa-newspaper fa-fw"></i></button>
  <button type="button" title="Title 2" (click)="getMyTitleTwo($event)" class="btn xbutton-square"><i class="fas fa-fw"></i></button>
</div>
```

My typescript code:

```
  getMyTitleOne($event) {
    console.log($event.target.title);
  }

  getMyTitleTwo($event) {
    console.log($event.target.title);
  }
```

But in my console sometimes I get values and sometimes I don't, very weird, but most of the time values are undefined:

[image]

Thanks guys
Cheers

Comment: That's because sometimes the $event.target is not the button but the `i` tag (the icon in your case).

Comment: Most probably you're clicking the <i> tag instead of the button sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use template variables :

```
<button #button1 (click)="log(button1.title)" title="Hello, world !">Click me !</button>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bvxtjz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: why there is template variable for button1 and for button2 there is not?

Comment: I removed the second button to not mess with my answer, because your issue was clicking on the wrong HTML element. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Roxy'Pro the advantage of template variables is that even if you click on your icon, the title will still be provided.

Comment: I didn't find need of template variable for the question of OP, that's the reason downvote from my side

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT Your solution doesn't work, it gives the same problem as the original code. Stop being bitter everytime I expose the issue of your code please.